# Executing SQL statements from an external .sql file

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have a `schema.sql` file containing an official DB structure in form of SQL statements such as:

```
CREATE TABLE directory (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,   base TEXT,   index_file TEXT,   default_ctype TEXT,   cache_ttl INTEGER DEFAULT 0);
CREATE TABLE handler (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    send_spec TEXT, 
    send_ident TEXT,
    recv_spec TEXT,
    recv_ident TEXT,
   raw_payload INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
   protocol TEXT DEFAULT 'json');
```

I would like to *apply* these statements to my database to create a compliant schema. Is there a clean approach to achieve this ?

Clean meaning here:

- pure Ruby / Sequel
- independent from the underlying DB engine
- without parsing the `.sql` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either I didn’t understand the goal properly or why not read the statements from the file and execute them with default `ActiveRecord` method?

```
ActiveRecord::Base.execute File.read('PATH_TO_FILE')
```

or with `Sequel`:

```
DB.run File.read('PATH_TO_FILE')
```

Comment: Because I did not just forget to tag my question [tag:activerecord] and need a [tag:sequel] answer. Having said that I looked at using a similar method in Sequel (`Database#run`) but I did not get the feeling it would happily accept statements truncated by newlines so I specifically asked if there was a simple approach before going with the manual loading.

Comment: Ah so, sorry. Anyway, `Database#run` has no problems with newlines; plus you may `gsub /\n/, ''` if you don’t want newlines to be there.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear that you're positive about the newline handling done by [tag:sequel]. However then why do you propose the `gsub` which I expect to join all lines together in a gigantic illegal SQL statement ?

Comment: I checked that [tag:sequel]'s `Database#run` does indeed handle my `.sql` file nicely despite the multiline statements. I should have had more faith. Please edit your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Actually, that′ very predictable since low-level methods like `Sequel::Database#run` and/or `ActiveRecord::Base#execute` do simply pass the argument as pure SQL to the database driver. BTW, I’ve an answer updated.

Comment: Note that `Sequel::Database#run` is not specified to handle multiple statements in a single string.  You are dealing with undefined behavior at that point, and it may work or not depending on the underlying driver.